# Access selected row element in telerik grid using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

How can I access selected members of a Telerik Grid using jquery? I have no idea about this, I tried the below method, but doesn't alert the innerText when select a row.

Here is My Grid:

```
            <td><%= Html.MyCustomGridFor("gridName", "refreshAction", "refreshController", GridOptions.EnableSelecting, Model).Columns(column =>
                    {
                        column.Bound(o => o.Code).Title("Code").Width("40px");
                        column.Bound(o => o.Description).Title("Description");
                    }).HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "gridName" , @style = "width: 200px;" })%>
            </td>
```

jquery:

```
$("#gridName").focusin(function(e){
   alert(e.innerText);

});
```

Comment: your selector is wrong `$("gridName")`

Comment: @YogeshWaran Thanks! Updated it to $("#gridName"). I get "undefined" error though

Comment: @YogeshWaran i got i to work using "e.srcElement.innerText" Is there anyway I can pass this value to a different function?

Comment: store this in global variable and use it in different function